# Spring Creating a table with averaged values

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

So I have set up a Postgres database backend using Spring Boot for a small project of mine.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table
@Entity
public class Proba {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPlayer", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Player player;

    private Long ability1;
    private Long ability2;
    private Long ability3;
    private Long sum;
    private BigDecimal result;
    private BigDecimal ratio;
    private String proportions;
```

Same ability values combinations can give you different results (for example 10/20/30 may give you a result of 97,65 but it can also be 100,54 etc). I want to create another table that wouldnt have the FK from the Player table but it would contain averaged results for all the ability entries. How do I go about it?

Comment: I'd with creating an entity for those average values and joining it with the player. How  updating happens depends on your requirements but I can see at least 2 approaches: 1) whenever abilities change recalculate the values in code, i.e. update the averages entity before saving the player or 2) create a (materialized) view, i.e. let the DB calculate the averages, and use the entity only for reading it.

Comment: @Thomas but how (and why?) would I join it with the Player if the averaged value doesnt belong to any single player?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. In that case it's probably easiest to use a view which gets updated whenever the table changes. Or you just use a query to calculate the averages whenever they are needed.

Comment: @Thomas could you maybe help me out with the query? Because for the love of god I cant make it work